# after install ubuntu 12.10, there's no anything just background and cursor

Tags: system-installation

I'm a newbie and knew linux ubuntu a month ago. I just installed ubuntu 12.10 with windows xp. It's success, but after login just background, no bar, no button and there is no anything. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with 12.10.  I would suggest downloading and installing 12.04, because it is an LTS, and will be supported until 2017.

I would also suggest using Lubuntu if your machine is really old and slow.

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/

Though the regular Ubuntu interface is very nice... you can get it here

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/